# Exclusively validating the presence of one parent ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, error-handling

I have a `Board` model that has the possibility of belonging to an `Artist`, `Album` or `BoardCategory`. I basically want to validate that if one of the three parent IDs is present the other remaining two cannot be added to the board. Being that I'm validating on multiple attributes I was wondering how to set up the `error.add` message. More importantly how do I accomplish this without creating such a lengthy `||` based conditional statement?

```
class Board << ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :artist
  belongs_to :album
  belongs_to :board_category

  validate :board_parent

  private
    def board_parent
      if artist_id.present? || album_id.present? || board_category_id.present?
        errors.add(..., "already belongs to an artist or album"
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if [artist_id, album_id, board_category_id].reduce.length > 1
    errors.add(:board, "Cant belong to both #{[! artist_id ||'Artist', !album_id||'Album', !board_category_id ||'Board Category'].select {|x| x != true}.join(' and ')}")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I would suggest you to modify your model structure. `polymorphic association` is what you really need. Here is the tutorial:

[polymorphic association](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association)